# run c# code from 2 buttons in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a Gridview with two buttons and I want to be able to run code when the user clicks on them. I have tried using `Row_command` and setting a `CommandName` on the buttons , but i am going round in circles! Help!

I cant seem to get the username name from the first cell in order to search for the user in the rowcommand:

```
protected void gridview_search_RowCommand(object sender, 
    GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "unlock_account")
   {
      string user = gridview_search.SelectedRow.Cells[0].ToString();  

      //run code when user is obtained 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was wrong for the command name part. I finally figured it out and then was able to get selected value from the gridview using DataKeys and was then able to
send this value to unlock user account.

```
    protected void gridview_search_RowCommand(object sender, 
    GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("unlock_account") == 0)
   {
      int user = (int)gridview_search.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value;

      //unlock account method
      userObj.unlockAccount(user);

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

should be able to set the event-handlers for those buttons to whichever function you are trying to run.

```
dgvbutton1.clickevent = dosomething();
dgvbutton2.clickevent = dosomething();
```

something along those lines should work

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="AddToCart" 
      CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
      Text="Add to Cart" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>    

      protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
          {
              // Retrieve the row index stored in the 
              // CommandArgument property.
              int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

              // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
              // from the Rows collection.
              GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

              // Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.
          }
      }
```